# How to Ensure the Correct Sorting on the Base of Date and Time in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am in a great confusion now. I have a comments table in mysql database. in comments table there is a field comment_posted_time (type DATETIME), I sort all the comments like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY comment_posted_time DESC";
```

Now, This can produce wrong results. I give you an example. Suppose there are two users sitting in front of computer, one in India and the other in America. Suppose India's Time is 10 hours forward from America. first the user from India posts a comment and its current local time is stored in comment_posted_time (type DATETIME). After 1 hour the user from America posts a comment and its current local time is stored in comment_posted_time (type DATETIME) as well. Now, in database the later posted comment from American User will not be counted the most current comment and sorting will not be correct.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference where are your users, your php and mysql are in one server, so you must not have a problem with times, You can show times for each user by his timezone converting it by php, but don't change mysql default timezone for each user. Design your `comments` table and set on `comment_posted_time` default value `NOW()`, and don't use this field in your insert queries. So all records in that field will saved in same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

How are getting the date for `comment_posted_time`?  Typically this would be the current date on the MySQL server.  If you're getting the datetime from the client machine (which I would NOT recommend), you could get the UTC date/time and then convert it back to the local time when you display it.

To store the current time from the MySQL server, you can do something like:

```
update comments set comment_posted_time = NOW() where id=...
```

This will not differ based on the client...

Comment: I am getting comment_posted_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), I don't know the core of date() function whether it gets the time and date from client's machine or from msyql server.

Comment: That's a PHP function.  That isn't dependent on the client at all.  It will get that date/time value from the PHP server.  As long as your web server time isn't changing, it should be consistent and the problem you're describing shouldn't exist...

Comment: is there any chance of my web server's time to change. If yes, then how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to its UNIX_TIMESTAMP and then sort by that.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(comment_posted_time) DESC";
```

You can read more about [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) documentation.

**Edit**:

You should not be storing the comment_posted_time relative to different timezones. All of the times should be relative to one timezone, like GMT, or the machine running php.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're facing the problem, that your users are in different timezones you should ALWAYS calculate timepoints to one given timezone bofore persisting it (usually you take the main servers timezone, or UTC per default). With this approach you can do both: order by timepoint and show users the timepoint calculated to their timezone.